# QObject connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QItemSelection'

Tags: qt, signals-slots

I got the following message around at time 23:59:59 pass to next day.
   I have no idea (since the codes were written by others) where it come from. 
   Could anyone suggest how to find out the problem?
   Thanks!

```
QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QItemSelection'
(Make sure 'QItemSelection' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QItemSelection'
(Make sure 'QItemSelection' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QItemSelection'
(Make sure 'QItemSelection' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the following outside of a namespace:

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(namespace::QItemSelection)
```

[Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmetatype.html)

Comment: That's probably there, as qRegisterMetaType() wouldn't compile otherwise. I guess it's the qRegisterMetaType() call itself that's missing. Execute qRegisterMetaType<QItemSelection>(); before it is used as such, e.g. on top of main().